# Python how to replace content in the capture group of regex?

Tags: python, regex

`-abc1234567-abc.jpg`

I wish to remove `-abc` before `.jpg`, and get `-abc1234567.jpg`. I tried `re.sub(r'\d(-abc).jpg$', '', string)`, but it will also replace contents outside of the capture group, and give me `-abc123456`. Is it possible to only replace the content in the capture group i.e. '-abc'?

Comment: You could use a positive look ahead: [`-abc(?=\.jpg)`](https://regex101.com/r/aU5kE0/1)

Comment: The documentation will tell you that you can use backreferences to substitute in the replacement string.

Comment: Use a capturing group on the pattern you need to keep. `re.sub(r'(\d)-abc\.jpg$', r'\1', string),`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use positive lookahead as follows.

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(\-abc)(?=\.jpg)')
test_str = u"-abc1234567-abc.jpg"
subst = u""

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

OR

You can use two capture groups as follows.

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(\-abc)(\.jpg)')
test_str = u"-abc1234567-abc.jpg"
subst = r"\2"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to remove -abc in only jpg files, you could use:

```
re.sub(r"-abc\.jpg$", ".jpg", string)
```

To use your code as close as possible: you should place '()' around the part you want to keep, not the part you want to remove. Then use `\g<NUMBER>` to select that part of the string. So:

```
re.sub(r'(.*)-abc(\.jpg)$', '\g<1>\g<2>', string)
```

Comment: A `.` in the pattern will match any character but a newline. I think you meant `s.replace("-abc.jpg", ".jpg")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, oops. Should have been `\.`. Well spot!